# Map Highlight Odd/Even Side of Street

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding, openstreetmap, bing-maps

I have two coordinates of a street. Either both Odd or Even.
So for example 15 ABC Street and 77 ABC Street (with their reverse geocode).

I'm trying to draw a path line that is near the sidewalk.

I used google maps api and did not find a way to do it.
The directions api draws a line in the middle of the road, and I cannot find a way to do a geometric translation to either side of the street.

I don't mind using any other API as long as I can solve the problem.

Comment: Is there no way for drawing a custom polyline using the Google Maps API? You can switch to Leaflet or OpenLayers which support drawing of custom shapes.

Comment: You can draw a custom polyline. But I don't see how you get the coordinates of the sidewalk. Also, If I reverse geocode an address, the point can be in the middle of a building.

Comment: Which country/area are you interested in? Bing Maps have roof top data for some areas which you could use to calculate if the address is left or right of a route line. I've done this before ages ago with Bing Maps.